# Count tap on button xcode

Tags: objective-c

I got a (stupid) question. I'm busy with a 'tap' app (i dont know how to name it) it's a game with a button in the middle of the screen and when a play start tapping the button it need's to count the click's.

Does anoyone know what i need to use (classes) in objective-c

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's better to start with a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook up an action to the tap event :

```
[button addTarget:self action: @selector(button_tapped) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And increment a counter when tapped (`tapCount` is a property of your view controller)

```
- (void)button_tapped
{
    self.tapCount += 1;
}
```

Comment: What file does that go in?